# Asp.net core invalid JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, post, httpclient

I have a problem sending a post request to my `asp.net` Server.

My Json looks like this:

```
{
     "Name":"NothingZeile224","FimDocument":"PHhkZjp4ZW5zY2hlbWEuMDEwMj4=","FimCodelistPicks":[]
}
```

And when I send it via a `HttpRequestMessage` in the `Body` to my Server I get this response:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|1db3b81f-4ca934b691097e16."
}
```

If I delete the brace in my JSON so it looks like this:

```
"Name":"NothingZeile224","FimDocument":"PHhkZjp4ZW5zY2hlbWEuMDEwMj4=","FimCodelistPicks":[]
```

It works.

But I don't get why? Does someone have an idea?

Thank you

Edit:

This is my Server Code:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/ConvertToCirali")]
        public async Task<string> ConvertToCirali([FromBody] string PostSendFim)
        {
            try
            {
                PostModel pm = (PostModel)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(PostSendFim);

                XDocument fim = XDocument.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(pm.FimDocument)));

                string jsonOutput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pm.FimCodelists);

                string MyContent = null;

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44398/api/FullCodelists"))
                    {
                        using (StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonOutput)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                        {
                            request.Content = stringContent;
                            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                            {
                                MyContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                List<MongoCodelist> ReturnedCodelists = new List<MongoCodelist>();
                ReturnedCodelists = (List<MongoCodelist>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyContent);

                FormatterFimToCirali fftc = new FormatterFimToCirali(fim, ReturnedCodelists);

                Debug.WriteLine("Hier steht der Text: " + fftc.CiraliFile.ToString());
                return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fftc.CiraliFile.ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry if it looks a bit weird, it is for a converter for files from a game

Comment: please add your server method to the question too.

Comment: Please show the code you use to send the request, and the code which receives it. Something odd is going on because it should work with valid JSON, and not work with invalid JSON, whereas you seem to have got the opposite situation. But we can't possibly make a diagnosis, or propose a cure, without first seeing the patient :-)

Comment: Hi sorry, I wanted to add it but I forgot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your parameter as string, so you need to send it a JSON string, not a JSON object. This string is then deserialized in your code at

```
PostModel pm = (PostModel)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(PostSendFim);
```

You can skip a step and let the framework do the deserialization for you. Just change the parameter type to `PostModel` instead of `string`.